# Space between input-groups in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the correct way to create a form with input like the one in the example with proper spacing between each input row?

What am I missing here?

http://bootply.com/98917

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use `form-group` to wrap the labels and inputs.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">X:</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-7">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">m</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Y:</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-7">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">m</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Z:</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-7">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
      <span class="input-group-addon">m</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://bootply.com/98919

Comment: You are right, I got confused by the docs; Don't mix with form groups
Do not apply input group classes directly to form groups. An input group is an isolated component. See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups